# nested for loops very slow with beautiful soup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have an xml file with a tree roughly like this.  Root has many A's, each A has many B's, each B has many Infos:

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b>
      <info>
        <stuff>
          ...
        </stuff>
      </info>
      <info>
        <stuff>
          ...
        </stuff>
      </info>
      ...
    </b>
  </a>
  ...
  <a>
    <b>
      <info>
        <stuff>
          ...
        </stuff>
      </info>
      <info>
      </info>
      ...
    </b>
  </a>
  ...
</root>
```

I am extracting the data to enter into a database. Each entry into the DB is made from different tags at different depths.  I have a series for for loops to go into the lowest depth node using BeautifulSoup to parse the xml. I've omitted the ORM and DB insert from the code because that is not where the bottleneck is.

```
for fn in glob.glob('/dir/*.xml'):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fn)

    all_a = soup.find_all('a')

    for a in all_a:
      blah = a.something.string
      blah2 = a.somethingelse.string
      all_b = a.find_all('b')

      for b in all_b:
         blah3 = b.somethingagain.string
         blah4 = b.again.string
         all_info = b.find_all('info')

         for info in all_info:
            blah5 = info.find('name')
            blah6 = info.almostdone.string

            #this is what gets inserted into db
            return (blah, blah2, blah3, blah4, blah5, blah6)
```

I am looping over a directory with thousands of xml files with glob.  This approach is going very very slow. Each return statement is going to be a new row in my DB.

I thought maybe using list comprehensions might speed things up, but it just very sloppy with the many depths of xml objects.

Is there a way to make this faster? Perhaps a better approach using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: lxml is going to be much faster than BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I noticed that you return from your innermost loop.  Does this mean that you only want the first "info" tag in the first "b" tag in the first "a" tag?  If so, there is no reason to `find_all` -- `find` would be sufficient.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I need to get the info from each A tag, and for each child of that A tag.  If I don't return from the innermost loop I don't get the right results. I couldn't get it to work with just .find. I get a navigable string error.